# How to update state after successful request with sources in alt.js?

Tags: javascript, flux, alt.js

I am fairly new to alt.js and have a question regarding updating the state in the success handler.

Let's say I have a UserStore and want to delete one User.
I fire the delete user action with the `id` of the user which is ought to be deleted. The source sends a delete request with that `id` to the backend. The request works and the sources fire the success action.

How do I remove the User from the StoreState in the success action handler, since I don't get the id or any other information about the made request passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [interceptResponse function](http://alt.js.org/docs/async/)

So, basically, you should have some construction like this in your DataSource:

```
deleteUser: {
   remote (state, id) {
      //Some backend call here
   },
   interceptResponse (data, action, args) {
      // Here you can access arguments, that were passed to the remote method 
      // via 'args' argument. What you return from this function will be passed
      // to further callbacks (success, error, etc.)

      return {data: data, id: args[0]};
   }
}
```

So in this case, with the data, returned by remote call, you will also pass the original id to the callbacks and will be able to delete the user from your store.